# How to do loadbalancing for collaborative editing with multi-az and geoproximity based routing policy

Tags: websockets, routing, load-balancing

I am planning a project which has users collaboratively editing a document. To provide good latency to users, I am planning to deploy in multiple AWS regions with active-active mongodb replicas with geoproximity based routing policy in AWS Route53. This plan conflicts with another requirement where users in a region (say Asia) should be able to work collaboratively on the same document with users from a different region (say North America), as users will get routed to the servers closest to them, and will work off of different databases.

On thinking a bit about the problem, the solution seems like writing a custom load-balancer which routes to the appropriate deployment based on the request-data and some queries to the db. Am I correct in my thinking? Also, how'd I handle forwarding web-socket connections to the correct server?

Comment: it is common to route clients to the closest 'edge' of your system then route the traffic internally to the 'node' that is hosting the 'shared data'. document editing is not particularly latency-sensitive so i would not run across many regions for latency performance so i would only use multiple regions for resilience. you probably don't need that until you are successful and scaling up so first solve the problem of proxing websocket traffic to the 'correct node' within a single region before you look at how you can use multiple regions for resilience.

Comment: on the specific question of forwarding websocket traffic that is more a "pick a framework and ask stackoverflow" sort of problem. as a random suggestion ;-) checkout RSocket as the protocol which speaks websocket. connect users to an edge node using rsocket over websockets, then proxy the messages using rsocket over TCP to the correct server. another random suggestion ;-) based on my experiences you would actually be better off using a scylladb than mongodb. scylladb (and Cassandra) are better for this sort of problem where you can use eventual consistency.